# How to make selection of ratio for for every 15 min

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not too familiar with SQL because i am asking for help from professionals :)

I have such statement which is calculating the unsuccessful ratio of transaction in % , but it is doing by whole day
The question is : How to change the statement in order it return the max value of the unsuccessful ratio for every 15 min ?  to see the  % for every 15 min in order to understand in which interval is the maximum unsuccessful transactions.

Statement is here: 
[image: Statement is here:]

[Test data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gh4c57xm19jn4z0/payments.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: see the link referenced to know on , how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: can you provide some sample data please, this would help a lot

Comment: Hi, i updated the post with link where is the test data

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the exact output is you want, but I guess you can start with this.

```
;WITH mCTE AS (
  SELECT p.*, CASE WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, p.server_time) >=0 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, p.server_time) < 15 THEN '0...14' 
                   WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, p.server_time) >=15 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, p.server_time) < 30 THEN '15...29'
                   WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, p.server_time) >=30 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, p.server_time) < 45 THEN '30...44'
                   WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, p.server_time) >=45 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, p.server_time) < 60 THEN '45...59'
              END AS mRange
  FROM payments AS p )

SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AS ReportDate, 
   YEAR(p.server_time) AS ServerYear, 
   MONTH(p.server_time) AS ServerMonth, 
   DAY(p.server_time) AS ServerDay, 
   DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) AS ServerHour, 
   p.mRange AS ServerMinuteRange, 
   COUNT(p2._total) / NULLIF(COUNT(p1._total) / 100.0, 0.0) AS Ratio
FROM mCTE AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN mCTE AS p1 ON p.row_id = p1.row_id AND (p._state / 1000) <> 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN mCTE AS p2 ON p.row_id = p2.row_id AND (p._state / 1000) = 1 AND p2.row_id IS NOT NULL
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, p.server_time) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
GROUP BY YEAR(p.server_time), MONTH(p.server_time), DAY(p.server_time), DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time), p.mRange
```

Result

```
ReportDate  ServerYear  ServerMonth  ServerDay  ServerHour  ServerMinuteRange  Ratio
2017-04-27  2017        4            27         13          0...14             0.000000000000000000
2017-04-27  2017        4            27         13          15...29            18.181818181818181818
2017-04-27  2017        4            27         13          30...44            0.000000000000000000
2017-04-27  2017        4            27         13          45...59            0.000000000000000000
2017-04-27  2017        4            27         14          0...14             18.181818181818181818
2017-04-27  2017        4            27         14          15...29            0.000000000000000000
2017-04-27  2017        4            27         14          30...44            0.000000000000000000
2017-04-27  2017        4            27         14          45...59            0.000000000000000000
2017-04-27  2017        4            27         15          0...14             0.000000000000000000
2017-04-27  2017        4            27         15          15...29            0.000000000000000000
2017-04-27  2017        4            27         15          30...44            0.000000000000000000
2017-04-27  2017        4            27         15          45...59            0.000000000000000000
2017-04-27  2017        4            27         16          0...14             0.000000000000000000
2017-04-27  2017        4            27         16          15...29            0.000000000000000000
```

**UPDATE**

For each three hours, just change the logic in the CTE and remove the minutes from the group by clause

```
;WITH mCTE AS (
   SELECT p.*, CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) >=0 AND DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) < 3 THEN '0...2' 
               WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) >= 3 AND DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) < 6 THEN '3...5'
               WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) >= 6 AND DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) < 9 THEN '6...8'
               WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) >= 9 AND DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) < 12 THEN '9...11'
               WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) >= 12 AND DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) < 15 THEN '12...14'
               WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) >= 15 AND DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) < 18 THEN '15...17'
               WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) >= 18 AND DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) < 21 THEN '18...20'
               WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) >= 21 AND DATEPART(HOUR, p.server_time) < 24 THEN '21...23'
          END AS mRange
   FROM payments AS p )

SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AS ReportDate, 
   YEAR(p.server_time) AS ServerYear, 
   MONTH(p.server_time) AS ServerMonth, 
   DAY(p.server_time) AS ServerDay, 
   p.mRange AS ServerHourRange, 
   COUNT(p2._total) / NULLIF(COUNT(p1._total) / 100.0, 0.0) AS Ratio
FROM mCTE AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN mCTE AS p1 ON p.row_id = p1.row_id AND (p._state / 1000) <> 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN mCTE AS p2 ON p.row_id = p2.row_id AND (p._state / 1000) = 1 AND p2.row_id IS NOT NULL
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, p.server_time) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
GROUP BY YEAR(p.server_time), MONTH(p.server_time), DAY(p.server_time), p.mRange
```

Result

```
ReportDate  ServerYear  ServerMonth  ServerDay  ServerHourRange  Ratio
2017-04-28  2017        4            26         18...20          1.754385964912280701
2017-04-28  2017        4            27         12...14          5.479452054794520547
2017-04-28  2017        4            27         15...17          0.000000000000000000
```

**Update 2**

To show only the last 3h of data you just have to change the WHERE clause to

```
WHERE p.server_time >= DATEADD(HOUR, -3, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin it looks working! But if i want to see the same data but for each 3 hours what i need to change in sql statement?

Comment: @AndrisSmits I updated the answer with the logic for each 3 hours

Comment: Kevin, yes, thank you very much! it works perfectly! But the last request - how to change the statement in order it shows values only for LAST 3 h ?